# Route Costing in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, vehicle-routing

I am trying to simulate a manufacturing system that uses Automated Guided Vehicles (AGVs) to carrying loads around the network to be processed. While the AGVs are travelling, it is ideal for them to pick the fastest route to the destination (not necessarily the shortest).

[Here is my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYxtJ.png)

I am kind of stuck at trying to implement a route costing algorithm, because I am not too familiar with the intricacies of this program yet. Can anyone kindly give me some rough idea on how it can be implemented in pseudo code with the following scenario:

The load needs to move from A to B and there are three possible paths. However, there is congestion in the red highlighted areas that will cause the load to take a longer time to reach point B.

How can I read the network to check for congestion and also calculate the various times needed to go to point B?

Comment: Welcome to SOF. To answer your question: Yes it is. Happy to help further but please aim for specific, concise questions to make our live as easy as possible :-) Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for your reply! I've kinda read through the help page on how to ask. May i understand what was the negative part about this question?

Comment: Sure Samuel. Your question is very open ended and not specific. You are not showing the work you already did to make it work. Instead of asking "is x possible?", ask something like "how do i make y work". Where "y" is your specific situation. Add Screenshots, explanations, specifics. Put in as much effort as you can to explain, clarify. Your question should take a lot of effort so our answer will not  Hope this helps, looking forward to learning about your actual problem.

Comment: Google for some "great sof question examples"

Comment: @Benjamin, I have a model which I have been working on but am clueless as to how to form a routing algorithm. Could you guide me a little bit here?

Comment: Hi Samuel, not sure if you read my suggestions above, but open-ended questions are really not the right thing here on StackOverFlow. Please ask specific questions :-)

Comment: ok my apologies will make sure i try to get a routing algo out before i ask again! :)